# Error loading image - MediumBlob

Tags: php, file-upload, blob

I made a system where the user can upload multiple images. These images are stored in the database in a field of type MEDIUMBLOB. Below the code that makes this feature.

```
//Configurações para a geração de um arquivo binário temporário
        $diretorio = "temp/";
        $nomeArquivo = "sipi_binario.img";

        if ($_FILES["arquivo"]["name"][0] != null) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"]); $i++) {

                $pFoto = $_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"][$i];

                move_uploaded_file($pFoto, $diretorio . $nomeArquivo);
                $pont = fopen($diretorio . $nomeArquivo, "rb");

                $dados[4][$i] = base64_encode(fread($pont, filesize($diretorio . $nomeArquivo)));
                $dados[5][$i] = $_FILES["arquivo"]["type"][$i];

                fclose($pont);
            }
        }
```

When the user selects a few iamgens, the system behaves correctly, but when the user selects for example 20 images, some of them start to get corrupted. See below:

[image]
Does anyone know how this surely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is a parallel processing on the same processor is lost if not created multiple thumbs, so it is necessary to change the following lines to:

```
move_uploaded_file($pFoto, $diretorio . $nomeArquivo . $i);
$pont = fopen($diretorio . $nomeArquivo . $i, "rb");
$dados[4][$i] = base64_encode(fread($pont, filesize($diretorio . $nomeArquivo . $i)));
```